# How to create subplots with a title for each group of data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Let's say I have a data frame defined as below:

```
cat = ['games','games','home','home','home','food','food','food','food','food']
dates = ['2024-07-01','2021-31-1', '2021-04-1', '2021-05-1','2021-02-2', '2021-05-1','2021-01-2','2021-14-2','2021-03-3','2021-11-4']
nums = [137, 338, 52, 144, 100, 5, 72, 400, 100, 99]

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':cat, 'dates':dates, 'nums':nums})
```

I want to plot each `cat` -- for example create a plot of the `nums` vs. `dates` for `games`, `home`, and `food` separately.

I get it by doing `df.groupby('cat').plot(x = 'date')`, which works, but I'm having trouble getting titles on each subplot. Or is there an easier way to achieve this and have each plot title be the name of the `cat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the groups, and this gives you full control over the axes, titles, etc., of each plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for key, gp in df.groupby('cat'):
    gp.plot('dates')
    plt.title(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

- The easiest way is the use `seaborn`, a high-level API for `matplotlib`, which works directly with long form data.
- When using [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) to create a figure-level plot with, the column specified for `row` will automatically have the unique values as the plot title.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# convert the date column to a datetime dtype
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, format='%Y-%d-%m')

# plot
p = sns.relplot(data=df, row='cat', x='dates', y='nums', kind='line', height=3, aspect=3, marker='o')
```

[image]